# How do I deal with the /dist directory on Heroku?

Tags: git, angularjs, heroku

I have a Yeoman-generated AngularJS app being served by an Express app on Heroku. The built app lives in the /dist directory, which is ignored by Git by default. I figured that to host on Heroku I have two options:

1. The /dist file needs to be under version control; or
2. The /dist directory needs to be built on Heroku.

It's a schlep to version control the /dist directory (since it changes all the time), so I'm keen to explore the the second option. I found a custom buildpack (https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt) that runs a build script on Heroku, creating the necessary /dist folder whenever you deploy.

My question is: won't the /dist directory be cleaned out with [Heroku's ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)?

(I've *very* new to all of this, so it might also be that I'm approaching this whole setup from the wrong angle - I'm open to suggestions)

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted as I'm in exactly the same position. I'm also confused because having the files in a dist folder will mean I have to edit where my css and js is served from.

Comment: I ended up using the custom buildpack mentioned in the question. Still not convinced that this is the *right* way of doing it.

Comment: I did too - I think it is the right way to go about it actually. I build locally as a kind of test now to see if Grunt is doing what I want it to do!